# Adding absolute uncertainties with different significant figures

Tags: error-analysis

I have to add two measures with their respectiuve absolute uncertainties, given by the instruments I have used to measure them. The measures are:

x = 0.486 +- 0.001 m
y = 0.01230 +- 0.00001 m

They have been measured with two different instruments with different sensibility. I need to find the final lenght.

As far as I know, when adding, we have to add also the relative uncertainties, so my result is:

x + y = 0.49830 +- 0.00101 m

Now I have to round off the measure to 3decimal figures (as the measure with less decimal figures), so it would be 0.498 but I dont know how to round off the uncertainty.

If I write +- 0.001, the result is less uncertain of what it should be... Let's say for example that I do the biggest error for both measures: I measure 0.49931, that is not inside the range of 0.498 +- 0.001

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> when adding, we have to add also the relative uncertainties

The [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) formula for addition is to add the variances. So you square the individual uncertainties, add the squares, and take the square root.